# what are the limitations to execute a binary which compiled actually on x86_64 machine into i686 machine?

Tags: linux, 32-vs-64-bit

i tried to compile sample hello_world.c program in x86-64 machine, but i expect to execute hello_world binary into i686 machine. can somebody correct me if i was wrong, what are the subjective limitations to execute x86-64 binary into i686 Machine. from my understanding x86-64 binary will execute in 32-bit machine aswell.

```
prashad@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
prashad@ubuntu:~$

 
root@Docsis-Gateway:/tmp# uname -a
Linux Docsis-Gateway 4.9.199-yocto-standard #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 6 22:38:09 UTC 2020 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112703/discussion-on-question-by-aaripaka-prashad-what-are-the-limitations-to-execute-a).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[i686](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P6_%28microarchitecture%29) packages are intended to be executed on Intel 32-bit x86 processors up to and including the
[Pentium 4](https://ark.intel.com/products/series/89613/Intel-Pentium-Processor-4000-Series)
and others, as well as
[AMD K6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_K6)
processors and other compatible 32-bit CPUs.

For more information see
[AMD K6](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=482324&seqNum=18) series
and
[Intel i686](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=482324&seqNum=17).

[x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)
is for processors compatible with the AMD64 64-bit platform and
[Intel 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#cite_note-11)
based processors.

64-bit processors are fully backward compatible with 32-bit predecessors,
so an AMD64 or Intel 64 processor supports both 64-bit x86_64 and 32-bit i686.
But for performance you may prefer the 64-bit x86_64 distribution packages.

However, a 32-bit computer can only execute i686 packages and cannot execute
x86_64 packages.

Reference :
[Microprocessor Types and Specifications](https://myonlineusb.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/what-is-the-difference-between-i386-i486-i586-i686-i786/).

Comment: thanks @harrymc . so for this question, i understand like this.                                 x86_64 binary must not execute in i686 machine.                                                      
aswell i686 binary can be execute on x86_64 machine.

Comment: Absolutely right.